# Showing a sequence is coherent

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For my question, I am considering $p$-adic numbers, where $p$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$.

A sequence $(x_k)$ is **coherent** if $x_{k+1} \equiv x_{k}\ (mod\ p^k)$ for a prime, $p$, and natural number $k \geq 1$.

Consider $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p \nmid a$ . Then for $k \geq 1$, $x_k := a^{p^{k-1}}$ and so $(x_k) = (a, a^p, a^{p^2}, a^{p^3}, ...)$.

**I want to show that $(x_k)$ is coherent**, but I'm stuck. I've tried considering $x_{k+1}-x_{k}$ and trying to find if $p^k$ divides this by using the definition of $x_k$, but am getting nowhere.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Let's start at the beginning. Can you prove $a^p\equiv a\bmod p$?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've now edited my post as I forgot to add that  $p \nmid a$. Even so, I don't see how to show what you've suggested, this is what I've been trying...

Comment: It's called Fermat's (Little) Theorem. It's in every introductory Number Theory textbook ever written. Go get one, and read it, and you'll have a starting point. I can't imagine anyone having any success studying $p$-adic numbers, who hasn't come across The Fermat result.